# pyodbc code errors for longer queries

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have tested some pyodbc code and works just fine when I artificially constrain the query to return smaller sets/run faster. But when I try to run w/o artificial constraints, I start getting errors.
Here's an example:

```
import pyodbc
#use only two days worth of data to artificially return a small sample
sql = """
select * into #T1 from MYTABLE where date between '11/1/2015' and '11/2/2105'
"""

#create a connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MyDatabase')  
#create a cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#execute SQL  
cursor.execute(sql)
#close the cursor
cursor.close()
#commit changes
cnxn.commit()

#now prepare to read T1
sql2 = ("""SELECT * FROM #T1""")

#create a cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#execute SQL to extract data
cursor.execute(sql2)

cursor.fetchone() #returns data as expected
```

Now I simply modify the initial sql by changing the date range. The initial cursor.execute(sql) takes much longer to run and when I execute sql2 I get an error:

```
sql = """
    select * into #T1 from MYTABLE where date between '1/1/2014' and '11/2/2105'
    """

#same code as in previous example
...

sql2 = ("""SELECT * FROM #T1""")

#create a cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
#execute SQL to extract data
cursor.execute(sql2)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-85-939a3a2fefc6>", line 6, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql2)

ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#T1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Seems almost as though the connection got closed. This never happens with quick queries.

Comment: If you `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)` what does it say?

Comment: 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:41:43) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: You might try `cnxn.timeout = 86400` or some other large value. The default is supposed to be `0` (no timeout, wait forever) but maybe there's something implementation-specific for SQL Server that is timing out the `SELECT ... INTO #T1` and causing that temp table to not exist.